Long Compiling and Execution Time
I've written a small program to format a text file. So far I am mostly statisfied with the result of my program. What is unaccaptble is the time it needs to compile and execute. It takes 6 seconds to compile and even longer to execute. Is fgetc the problem?
The Content of the file that is read is
Hartman-Montgomery, Jane R.
Doe, J. D.

Code:
#include <stdio.h>

#define LENGTH_FIRST_NAME 10
#define LENGTH_SUR_NAME 15
#define NUMBER_NAMES 2

void get_data(FILE *file_ptr, char first[][LENGTH_FIRST_NAME], char middle[][LENGTH_FIRST_NAME], char surname[][LENGTH_SUR_NAME], int number_items);

int main()
{
    char    first[NUMBER_NAMES][LENGTH_FIRST_NAME] = {0},
            middle[NUMBER_NAMES][LENGTH_FIRST_NAME] = {0},
            surname[NUMBER_NAMES][LENGTH_SUR_NAME] = {0};

    FILE *file_ptr;

    if((file_ptr = fopen("names.txt", "r")) != 0)
        puts("--File Found--");
    else
        puts("--File not Found--");

    get_data(file_ptr, first, middle, surname, NUMBER_NAMES);

    /*for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_NAMES; i++)
    {
        printf("%s", first[i]);
        printf("%20s", middle[i]);
        printf("%20s\n", surname[i]);
    }*/

    fclose(file_ptr);

    return 0;
}

void get_data(FILE *file_ptr, char first[][LENGTH_FIRST_NAME], char middle[][LENGTH_FIRST_NAME], char surname[][LENGTH_SUR_NAME], int number_items)
{
    int ch = 0,
        i = 0;

    for(int j = 0; j < number_items; j++)
    {
        i = 0;
        while((ch = fgetc(file_ptr)) != ',' && i < LENGTH_FIRST_NAME - 1)
            first[j][i++] = ch;
        first[j][i] = '\0';


        while(ch != ' ')
            ch = fgetc(file_ptr);

        i = 0;
        while((ch = fgetc(file_ptr)) != ' ')
            middle[j][i++] = ch;
        middle[j][i] = '\0';

        while(ch != ' ')
            ch = fgetc(file_ptr);

        i = 0;
        while((ch = fgetc(file_ptr)) != '\n' && i < LENGTH_SUR_NAME - 1 && ch != EOF)
            surname[j][i++] = ch;
        surname[j][i] = '\0';

    }
}


How do you compile the program? With my GCC 12.2 it takes about 50 ms.

I just compiled that code and it took less than a second. you must be running on a very slow system. Also, reading the file character by character is far less efficient than reading a line at a time and tokenising the input.

Executing it takes about 3 ms if the names.txt file was written (if not, there is a segfault).

i am compiling it in CODE:BLOCKS. It is using GNU GCC COMPILER but I am not advanced enough to tell you what version is being used. My system is also advanced enough to run modern games and edit videos. I doubt that my setup is the reason. The file is in the same folder as the program.

That is part of the task. to limit the first name to 10 chars. it is from a book.

Please note that fgetc returns EOF, on failure, which is different from ' '.

no everything is on my computer and in the same folder.

Try disabling your antivirus.

If you compile and run a simple "Hello World" program, is everything also slow?

OT: BTW, the error handling in case the file does not exist (IOW if fopen returns NULL), is wrong. Look closely at your code and consider what your code does in that case.

If i turn the function get_data() into a comment everything is superfast. so this seems to be the problem.

I would also suspect so-called "anti" viruses. The main difference between an "anti" virus and a virus is that the former costs money. Both lag down your computer and prevent you from using it as intended. The best protection from viruses is to not bloody download them from the Internet or open fishy mail attachments. The best protection from "anti" viruses is to uninstall them from your hard drive.

Completely tangential to the speed issues — Don't forget that some people don't have middle names (for instance, I don't).  And on the Indian subcontinent, it is not unusual for people to have just one name — no surname.  However, those are details beyond what you need for an introductory programming exercise.

that is true but it was part of the task which i posted in the answer below.

@PeterKirsch actually your code should probably be able to handle names without middle names. In that case the middle would be a zero length string. You can add this feature later if necessary, or just for fun.

Consider a structure to contain the related arrays. Passing a single array of structures is better than passing multiple arrays.
Try fgets to read a line and then parse with sscanf.
Use %n to track progress through the line. It provides the number of characters processed by the scan to the point of the %n specifier.
#include <stdio.h>

#define LENGTH_FIRST_NAME 9
#define LENGTH_SUR_NAME 14
#define NUMBER_NAMES 2
#define SIZE 100
// stringify to use in format string
#define FS(x) SFS(x)
#define SFS(x) #x

typedef struct person_s {
    char first[LENGTH_FIRST_NAME + 1];
    char middle[LENGTH_FIRST_NAME + 1];
    char surname[LENGTH_SUR_NAME + 1];
} person_t;

void get_data(FILE *file_ptr, person_t *person, int number_items);

int main()
{
    char *filename = "names.txt";
    FILE *file_ptr;
    person_t person[NUMBER_NAMES] = { 0};

    if ( NULL != ( file_ptr = fopen ( filename, "r"))) {
        puts ( "--File Found--");
    }
    else {
        perror ( filename);
        return 1;
    }

    get_data ( file_ptr, person, NUMBER_NAMES);

    for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_NAMES; i++)
    {
        printf("%12s", person[i].first);
        printf("%20s", person[i].middle);
        printf("%20s\n", person[i].surname);
    }

    fclose ( file_ptr);

    return 0;
}

void get_data(FILE *file_ptr, person_t *person, int number_items) {
    char line[SIZE] = "";
    int used = 0;
    int offset = 0;
    int count = 0;

    while ( count < number_items && fgets ( line, sizeof line, file_ptr)) {
        offset = 0;
        used = 0;
        if ( 1 != sscanf ( line + offset, " %"FS(LENGTH_FIRST_NAME)"[^,]%n", person[count].first, &used)) {
            break;
        }
        offset += used;
        used = 0;
        sscanf ( line + offset, "%*[^ ]%n", &used);
        offset += used;
        used = 0;
        if ( 1 != sscanf ( line + offset, " %"FS(LENGTH_FIRST_NAME)"[^ ]%n", person[count].middle, &used)) {
            break;
        }
        offset += used;
        used = 0;

        if ( 1 != sscanf ( line + offset, " %"FS(LENGTH_SUR_NAME)"[^\n]", person[count].surname)) {
            break;
        }
        ++count;
    }
}


So thx for all the tips and tricks. I "solved" the issue by buffering the lines from the txt into a string array and then i rearranged the data to the tasks specifications.
I will post the task and then my solution so you can follow.

Write a program that processes a data file of names in which each name is on a
separate line of at most 80 characters. Here are two sample names:
Hartman-Montgomery, Jane R.
Doe, J. D.
On each line the surname is followed by a comma and a space. Next comes
the first name or initial, then a space and the middle initial. Your program
should scan the names into three arrays—surname, first, and middle_init.
If the surname is longer than 15 characters, store only the first 15. Similarly,limit the first name to ten characters. Do not store periods in the first and middle_init arrays. Write the array’s contents to a file, aligning the contents of each column.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LENGTH_FIRST_NAME 10
#define LENGTH_SUR_NAME 15
#define NUMBER_NAMES 2

#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 80

#define SPACING 30

void get_data(FILE *input_file_ptr, FILE *output_file_ptr, char first[LENGTH_FIRST_NAME], char middle[LENGTH_FIRST_NAME], char surname[LENGTH_SUR_NAME], int number_items);

int main()
{
    char    first[LENGTH_FIRST_NAME] = {0},
            middle[LENGTH_FIRST_NAME] = {0},
            surname[LENGTH_SUR_NAME] = {0};

    FILE *input_file_ptr;

    if((input_file_ptr = fopen("names.txt", "r")) != 0)
        puts("--File Found--");
    else
        puts("--File not Found--");

    FILE *output_file_ptr;

    output_file_ptr = fopen("names_output.txt", "w");

    get_data(input_file_ptr, output_file_ptr, first, middle, surname, NUMBER_NAMES);

    fclose(input_file_ptr);
    fclose(output_file_ptr);

    return 0;
}

void get_data(FILE *input_file_ptr, FILE *output_file_ptr, char first[LENGTH_FIRST_NAME], char middle[LENGTH_FIRST_NAME], char surname[LENGTH_SUR_NAME], int number_items)
{
    char buffer[MAX_STRING_LENGTH] = {0};

    for(int j = 0; j < number_items; j++)
    {
        //fill the arrays
        //buffer each line at a time
        fgets(buffer, MAX_STRING_LENGTH, input_file_ptr);

        int k = 0,
            i = 0;

        for(i = 0; i < LENGTH_SUR_NAME - 1 && buffer[k] != ','; i++)
            surname[i] = buffer[k++];
        surname[i] = '\0';

        while(buffer[k] != ' ')
            k++;
        if(buffer[k] == ' ')
            k++;

        for(i = 0; i < LENGTH_FIRST_NAME - 1 && buffer[k] != '.' && buffer[k] != ' '; i++)
            first[i] = buffer[k++];
        first[i] = '\0';

        while(buffer[k] != ' ')
            k++;
        if(buffer[k] == ' ')
            k++;

        for(i = 0; i < LENGTH_FIRST_NAME - 1  && buffer[k] != '.' && buffer[k] != EOF; i++)
            middle[i] = buffer[k++];
        middle[i] = '\0';

        //copy the arrays to the output file
        fprintf(output_file_ptr, "%-30s%-30s%s\n", surname, first, middle);
    }
}

